# How to change to multiple screens by one same button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm coding in Objective-C using XCode 4.6 on a MacBook Pro, and I want to know how to use the same button in my storyboard to get connected to two different screens, I mean, I want to put a condition estructure to decide to which screen the app is going when the user press the button, for example    if(x==1) {go to view controller 1} else {go to view controller 2}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect segues from your view controller (not the button) in storyboard. Give the button an IBAction and throw your if statement in the implementation of the IBAction:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    if (x == 1) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Go to view controller 1" sender:self];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Go to view controller 2" sender:self];

    }
}
```

Comment: But wait, now im having the "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error, how can I solve it?